# Firestore transaction fails only silently

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I am trying to:

1. read a value from a document
2. update a document.

However, I would like the transaction to fail if another process made a modification to the same document between 1 and 2.

I simulated it with the debugger (stopping after 1, make a modification on the document and resume). As a result, the transaction does not seem to be applied but I do not get any error. I would like a real failure with an exception. How can I achieve that?

```
transaction = db.transaction()
doc_ref = db.collection('mycollection').document('mydoc')

    @firestore.transactional
    def update_in_transaction(transaction, doc_ref):
        snapshot = doc_ref.get(transaction=transaction)
        my_value = snapshot.get(u'my_value')
        transaction.update(doc_ref, {
            u'my_value': 'someothervalue'
        })

update_in_transaction(transaction, doc_ref)
```

Comment: I wonder if you could use something like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) and use it as the error you mentioned.

I wasn't able to find it for python, I'll comment again if I find similar documentation for python.